# Powershell: Cmdlet to access sub properties in the pipeline

Tags: powershell, pipeline

In powershell (7.3.x), I'm currently reading a json file (or an xml file) and I want to access a nested property within the pipeline without having to wrap stuff in parentheses. Let me explain what I've found, and what I'm actually looking for.

### Input File

My data is stored in a file named `data.json`:

```json
{
  "building1": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "5d119bb9-7adb-44e0-84b8-d00e8d16e75f",
        "status": "COLLAPSED",
        "startDateTime": "2022-10-21T08:32:09Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  "building2": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "f5b31978-6475-4b55-b836-484c0ca7818b",
        "status": "ONGOING",
        "startDateTime": "2023-01-21T12:32:09Z"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### Goal & Constraints

I want to show the `id` and `status` of `building1` with a single powershell pipeline without using parentheses (nor using jq, since this is about powershell hashtables and pscustomobjects at its heart).

### Solution 0

This solution is using parentheses, and it works well, but is annoying to write, since you have to go back and put parentheses while writing it:

```
(Get-Content ./data.json | ConvertFrom-Json).building1.data | Select-Object id, status
```

### Solution 1

I can use a `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` one at a time, but it becomes very long very quickly:

```
Get-Content ./data.json | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty building1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty data | Select-Object id, status
```

### Almost Solution 2

Using a computation expression, I can do something that almost works, but does not allow the final projection with `Select-Object id, status`:

```
Get-Content ./data.json | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object {$_.building1.data}
```

It's possible to fix this by repeating the computation expression, but is not ideal:

```
Get-Content ./data.json | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object {$_.building1.data.id}, {$_.building1.data.status}
```

### Ideal Solution

Looking at the powershell galery, I expected to find a cmdlet named `Get-Object` that could be used this way:

```
Get-Content ./data.json | ConvertFrom-Json | Get-Object building1.data | Select-Object id, status
```

But I could not find anything like that.

Is there such a cmdlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call to extract the nested object of interest:

```bash
Get-Content -Raw ./data.json | 
  ConvertFrom-Json |
  ForEach-Object { $_.building1.data } |
  Select-Object id, status
```

If you want to avoid an extra command, using [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) is an option, but invariably involves the duplication you'd like to avoid:

```bash
Get-Content -Raw ./data.json | 
  ConvertFrom-Json |
  Select-Object @{ n='id'; e = { $_.building1.data.id } }, 
                @{ n='status'; e = { $_.building1.data.status } }
```

---

Note it **would indeed be nice to be able to do pass property name *paths* to [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)**, but this **does *not* currently work**, because a `-Property` argument such as `building1.data.id` is invariably considered a *single* property name, i.e. a property whose (unusual) name is *verbatim* `building1.data.id`

[GitHub issue #14633](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14633) is a **feature request** to allow interpretation of dotted arguments *as paths*, such as via a `-ByNamePath` switch that changes the interpretation of the (often positionally implied) `-Property` arguments to property *paths*:

```bash
# WISHFUL THINKING as of PowerShell 7.3.6
Get-Content -Raw ./data.json | 
  ConvertFrom-Json |
  Select-Object -ByNamePath -Property building1.data.id, building1.data.status
```

Comment: @DougMaurer, it is indeed meant to be a switch parameter that _complements_ the (positional) `-Property` parameter. I've updated the answer to make that clear. Thanks for pointing out the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom function that traverses an object on a given path like what you were expecting. Definitely recommend you to just use a loop as demonstrated in [mklement0's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76954725/15339544) though.

```bash
function Get-Object {
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, Mandatory)]
        [object] $InputObject,

        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)]
        [string] $Path
    )

    begin {
        $tokens = $Path.Split('.', [System.StringSplitOptions]::TrimEntries) 
    }
    process {
        foreach ($token in $tokens) {
            $InputObject = $InputObject.$token
            if (-not $InputObject) {
                # here you can add a warning that no such path exists
                return
            }
        }

        $InputObject
    }
}
```

Then you can:

```
$json | ConvertFrom-Json |
    Get-Object building1.data |
    Select-Object id, status

# Outputs:
#
# id                                   status
# --                                   ------
# 5d119bb9-7adb-44e0-84b8-d00e8d16e75f COLLAPSED
```